# Readonly field vs. readonly property

Tags: c#

Sometimes I see classes defined with readonly members like so:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly string bar;

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public string Bar => bar;
}
```

and other times I see classes defined with readonly members like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }

    public string Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

The second example looks a lot more readable/succinct to me, but I was wondering if there is any legitimate reason for explicitly defining a `readonly` backing field (as per the first example) ?

*Qudos for an in-depth analysis of the two examples, ideally covering what's really going on under the hood, in the CLR.*

Comment: Actually, the 2nd version is very very different. A equivalent version would be `public string Bar {get;}` The example you posted of `public string Bar { get; private set; }` is not read only, it is just not publicly settable.

Comment: Scott, your comment should be an answer.  Well said sir.

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @user1620220 why? Are you using < C# 6?

Comment: Yeah I'm using c# 5. I guess that explains it.

Comment: @user1620220 quite so. Time for an upgrade me thinks :-)

Comment: @series0ne If you really like the second, then you can make it fully equivalent of the first one by simply removing the setter, e.g. `public string Bar { get; }`. Yet another C#6 improvement.

Comment: The second option is not actually readonly - it's mutable because the value could be changed at any point from the owner instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is a short way of writing

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly string bar;
    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public string get_Bar() { return this.bar; }
}
```

That's all a property with a getter is; it's just a short way of writing a getter function.

The second is a short way of writing

```
class Foo
{
  private string __bar;
  public Foo(string bar)
  {
      this.set_Bar(bar);
  }
  public string get_Bar() { return this.__bar; }
  private void set_Bar(string b) { this.__bar = b; }
}
```

Where again, a property is just a pair of get/set methods behind the scenes.

> I was wondering if there is any legitimate reason for explicitly defining a readonly backing field

Either form is perfectly legitimate. Pick the one you like better.

I note that the two forms are not equivalent. In the first case the property's backing field can only be changed in the constructor; in the latter, the property's backing field can be changed anywhere in the class.

Comment: Does reflection have any impact on either?

Comment: @series0ne: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Well presumably I can't call a setter on the first example since it doesn't have one, and presumably regardless of it being readonly, reflection would let me change the value willy-nilly?

Comment: @series0ne: If your component is granted private reflection permission then your component can do literally anything it wants. Full trust means **full trust** -- you get to break the rules and are responsible for understanding the **full** consequences of doing so.  If you feel like using private reflection permission to muck around with values of implementation details, that's your right.

Comment: Isn't the last paragraph in the answer the only thing that matters in deciding what to use? If you want to alter the value outside the constructor don't use a readonly backing field otherwise leave it readonly or am I missing something?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you also explain the new feature (readonly) auto implemented property without `set` and its equivalent with backing field?